# Configure Tomcat as a service (no catalina.bat)

Tags: tomcat

I install Tomcat as a service using the installer from Apache website. I don't have catalina.bat in my bin folder. How can I set the permgem memory size? Any recommended size to set?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use tomcatXw.exe (where X is your major Tomcat version) to configure the service: there are places to configure all JVM options, there.

Answer (score 1):

To Configure Tomcat's `Java_OPT` in catalina,
First of all in Installer adaddition of tomcat, you never find out `catalina`  file in bin Folder.

To set parameters you have to use `tomcate property`(use tomcatXw.exe to open that)
Giving little idea how to set param in property file.

**In catalina file**:(write something like this)

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms2048m -Xmx4048m -XX:NewSize=1024m -XX:MaxNewSize=2048m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

**In Tomcate Property file**:(add your parameter in `Java options:` same as in picture)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This link tells how to configure heap max size on tomcat7 exe installation where we don't have catalina.bat file. http://plavc.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/tomcat-service-on-windows/