# net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK) from tomcat in a struts application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, struts2

I have 2 jsps and both the jsps are trying to load 2 different tables and I am using display:table tag for the same.

I want to use pagination for the tables so while the pages are getting loaded, the jsp which is supposed to have less data (around 500 records) is working perfectly fine and the 2nd jsp which is supposed to show more data (around 40K records)  is throwing this error -

net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)

Weirdly the same logic is working perfectly on my local machine and when I am deploying the same web application in the tomcat on windows server, I am getting this issue.

I have seen a lot of posts related to this question and most of them talk about increasing the buffer size. I have tried all those things but no luck.

Any leads will be appreciated.

```
div id="flip-tabs">
            <ul id="flip-navigation">
                <li class="selected"><a href="#" id="tab-0">Company Master</a></li>  
                <li>
                <a href="showIndividualFieldsOCB.action" id="tab-1" >Individual Master</a>
                </li>  
            </ul>
            <br/>

            <s:form id="frmOcbCompanyMaster" name="frmOcbCompanyMaster" theme="simple" action="showCompanyFieldsOCB">
                <s:div id="divDisplayFields" name="divDisplayFields" theme="ajax">
                    <display:table name="requestScope.rsField.rows" form="frmOcbCompanyMaster" excludedParams="*" pagesize="4" class="its" style="border: 1px solid #666" sort="list" requestURI="" keepStatus="true">
                        <display:column title="Contact_Id" property="contact_id" />
                        <display:column title="SC_COMPANY_NAME" property="sc_company_name" />
                    </display:table>
                </s:div>
            </s:form>
</div>
```

So there are 2 tabs on the top, on click of another tab 'a href="showIndividualFieldsOCB.action"'
I am loading a different page which again has a table lime -

```
<display:table name="requestScope.rsField.rows" form="frmOcbIndividualMaster" excludedParams="*" pagesize="10" class="its" style="border: 1px solid #666" sort="list" requestURI="" keepStatus="true">
                        <display:column title="Contact_Id" property="contact_id" />
                        <display:column title="TP_SYSTEM" property="tp_system" />
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of web searches I figured the issue out. The issue was because of the java heap memory getting full.

I overcame the issue by following this thread :

[Tomcat crashes with error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882071/tomcat-crashes-with-error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded/45070211#45070211)